# The system cannot find the file specified in Visual Studio 2013 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am learning C++ for the first day, went on to type in this code from the first Chapter of "C++ A Beginner's Guide":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "C++ is power prgramming.";
return 0;
}
```

then when I debug it, I get an error message saying:

"Unable to start program 'F:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Projects1\Debug\Project1.exe'.
The system cannot find the file specified."

The error in output shows:

```
1>CL : Command line warning D4024: unrecognized source file type '?', object file assumed
1>  Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 12.00.31101.0
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>  
1>  /out: 
1>  ?.exe 
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1146: no argument specified with option '/out:'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I looked though a few posts that seems similar but none of the answers helped me. I had tried to add Additional Library Directories in the properties but still doesn't help. Tried compiling before debugging but still same error came out.
I just installed Visual Studio today so there is not point of restoring Default.

What else can I do?
Thanks very much.

Comment: What is the name of your source file?  For a simple program like that you should not need to change any project defaults at all.  Assuming your source file has a reasonable name and you haven't broken the project settings too much I'd look at an overly aggressive virus scanner quarantining your executable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The Source file name is main.cpp. Doesnt seem to be antivirus though. I am using BitDefender and I see nothing associated to visual studio in the events.